# How to serialize a generic class that can be its own type parameter?

Tags: java, generics, serialization, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

EDIT 2 : Problem solved. Props to Joachim Sauer and Viral Lalakia for their answers.

**Solution :** SonarLint won't make a warning if I swap the `Comparable<T>` and the `Serializable` for the type `T`. The warning it gives should be considered a false positive.

---

**Initial issue :**

So, I have a generic class `Pair<T>` that I want to be `Serializable` and `Comparable`.
Moreover, I *want* `T` to be `Comparable` (and I *need* it to be `Serializable` for `Pair<T>` to be Serializable too).

The class `PairCoord` inherits from it, with `T` being an `Integer`.

I'm using SonarLint for code analysis, and I'm trying to force myself to follow every advice (especially highly important ones), and it keeps warning me about the generic class `Pair`'s attributes not being serializables, despite having marked them as so.

Here is what I did :

```java
public class Pair<T extends Comparable<? super T> & Serializable> implements Comparable<Pair<T>>, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5797102044530257848L;
    
    
    private T first;
    private T last;

    public Pair(T first, T last) {
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
    }
    public Pair() {
    }

    // And so on
}

public class PairCoord extends Pair<Integer> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8389593640798914292L;
    

    public PairCoord(int first, int last) {
        super(first, (last + 8) % 8);
        // Since each of the 3 squares are loops, the node before n°0 is therefore n°-1
        // Except that n°-1 doesn't exist, but (-1 mod 8) = 7 
        // The only issue is that % isn't a modulo, but the remain of the euclidean division
        // So by adding 8 to "last", I make sure that the number in the operation is positive,
        // and since for all x >= 0, % behaves like mod, I have my node number correct (between 0 and 7) 
    }

}
```

And I have SonarLint Critical Warnings on the `first` and `last` fields as them being not serializable, even though I marked them as so ('Fields in a "Serializable" class should either be transient or serializable')

What could I do to fix that (if it is possible) ?

(Edit 1 : typo)

Comment: This is probably an issue with sonarlint not grasping your code. That might be because the *erasure* of `T` is `Comparable` which doesn't guarantee serializablilty, so if you ignore compiler warnings you *could* constructan unserializable `Pair`. But mostly this is just a false positive.

Comment: If you change sequence of `Comparable` and `Serializable` to make it like `T extends Serializable & Comparable<? super T>`, sonar doesn't give warning about `first` and `last` not being serializable. I am not sure about the reason behind that. I couldn't find such rule. There might be some possible issue with Sonar.

Comment: @ViralLalakia: that probably works because it changes the erasure (i.e. the actual underlying type used by the JVM in the absence of runtime generic information) of `T` from `Comparable` to `Serializable`.

Answer (score -3):

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5797102044530257848L;

```
private T first;
private T last;

public Pair(T first, T last) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
}
public Pair() {
}

// And so on
```

}

public class PairCoord extends Pair implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8389593640798914292L;


public PairCoord(int first, int last) {
    super(first, (last + 8) % 8);
    // Since each of the 3 squares are loops, the node before n°0 is therefore n°-1
    // Except that n°-1 doesn't exist, but (-1 mod 8) = 7 
    // The only issue is that % isn't a modulo, but the remain of the euclidean division
    // So by adding 8 to "last", I make sure that the number in the operation is positive,
    // and since for all x >= 0, % behaves like mod, I have my node number correct (between 0 and 7) 
}
```

}

Comment: What is this meant to improve? When posting answers, please *describe* what you're doing and don't just post code only.